# Intermittent failure using Excel VBA for chart series data in external workbook

Tags: vba, excel, charts, series

There are two workbooks, MakePlots.xlsm and ext_data.xlsm.  MakePlot contains an instruction sheet named PlotMe, a reference data set, and a number of reference plot sheets named Page 1, Page 2, etc.  ext_data contains sheets of run data, e.g. run 1, run 2, ...   The plot sheets contain a number of charts (i.e. 14 charts) that are arranged to print on one page to a pdf file.  There is a macro in MakePlots.xlsm, that reads initialization data off of sheet PlotMe, and then the macro copies the reference sheets, and updates the series in each chart with the reference to [ext_data.xlsm]run xxx!...., correcting the source and the number of rows.  In each series, the reference to Data is replaced with [ext_data.xlsm]run xxx and the number of rows is corrected.  The reference sheets identify the columns to plot in each chart, along with the number of series on each chart, and x/y labels, legend labels, etc.  Unfortunately, the macro occasionally doesn't work, illustrated below with pseudo code and output.  Previously, the macro also copied the sheet from ext_data into MakePlots, and then the reference source was changed from Data to "Run XXX".  That previously ran without error.  However, I thought it would be better to reference the external worksheet instead of copying the data sheets.  But now the macro doesn't always work.

Pseudo code

```
Loop mySrs In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
debug.print "Original formula: " & mySrs.Formula
... code to extract formula parts
debug.print "Reconstruct fmla: " & reconstructFmla
... code to modify series data source
debug.print "Proposed formula: " & updatedFmla
mySrs.Formula = updatedFmla   <- ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
debug.print "Updated  formula: " & mySrs.Formula  
end loop
```

I'm receiving errors illustrated with the following debug printing

```
  Original formula: =SERIES(,'Data'!$B$2:$B$204,'Data'!$C$2:$C$204,1)
  Reconstruct fmla: =SERIES(,'Data'!$B$2:$B$204,'Data'!$C$2:$C$204,1)
  Proposed formula: =SERIES(,'[ext_data.xlsm]Run XXX'!$B$2:$B$13,'[ext_data.xlsm]Run XXX'!$C$2:$C$13,1)
  NEXT LINE SHOWS THE ERROR, THE FORMULA WAS NOT COPIED INTO THE SERIES
  Updated  formula: =SERIES(,PlotMe!$B$2:$B$13,PlotMe!$C$2:$C$13,1)
```

If I go to the chart being updated, and scroll till the series formula

```
  =SERIES(,'Data'!$B$2:$B$204,'Data'!$C$2:$C$204,1)
```

appears in the formula bar, and then replace with the proposed formula, the chart updates correctly.  This doesn't seem to happen often, but it happens on the same chart and run.  There are 14 different charts and a large number of runs.  It only occurs on one of the 14 chart, and only on some of the runs.  If I stop the code right when the error is going to occur, and update the chart by copying the proposed formula into the formula bar, then the code continues running without error.  I'm unclear how to debug this further. How to determine why the formula string can not be updated with a formula that works in the formula bar?

Previously, the vba code was running when the external data was copied into the workbook with the charts, prior to updating the source links.  But it seems redundant, and potentially error prone, to generate copies of the data for the charts.

Temporary work around.  If proposed formula != update formula, then write proposed formula to a text file so that it can be copied in later, and put a text message on the plot indicating the data is incorrect.

Comment: Did you try with the source workbook (`ext_data.xlsm`) open? Besides where does this `PlotMe` name come from?

Comment: The code does open the ext_data.xlsm workbook prior to updating the references.  PlotMe is the name of the first sheet of the workbook with the plotting macro.   The workbook with the macro is named MakePlots.xlsm. MakePlot contains "reference" sheets that are set up based on one run.  Then the sub function in MakePlot copies the reference sheets renamed with the run number and sheet page number, and then updates the charts in the reference sheets to point to the run number sheet in ext_data.xlsm.